# PHP function to make more values = 0 if an id = 52 (value)

Tags: php

Hello i have a table when i want to display some td value = 0 if the status of the task has the id=52!
Down i will put a picture of the table!
I tried to use this code for that:
`if ($status['id'])  { $calC = $calCminusrealcost = $realCost =0; }` 
Here $calC, $calCminusrealcost and $realCost are the values i want to become 0!

Here is the pucture of the table: [!https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWOwb.png][1]][1]

So after i use this code it works but in general for all tasks, not just for those which have the id = 52, and if i try to replace id with 52 in the function it doesn't work!
Does someone know what can I do?

this is the full code i have about status:

```
    $outputStatus    = '';

    $outputStatus .= '<span class="inline-block label" style="color:' . $status['color'] . ';border:1px solid ' . $status['color'] . '" task-status-table="' . $aRow['status'] . '">';

    $outputStatus .= $status['name'];

    if ($canChangeStatus) {
        $outputStatus .= '<div class="dropdown inline-block mleft5 table-export-exclude">';
        $outputStatus .= '<a href="#" style="font-size:14px;vertical-align:middle;" class="dropdown-toggle text-dark" id="tableTaskStatus-' . $aRow['id'] . '" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">';
        $outputStatus .= '<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="' . _l('ticket_single_change_status') . '"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>';
        $outputStatus .= '</a>';

        $outputStatus .= '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="tableTaskStatus-' . $aRow['id'] . '">';
        foreach ($task_statuses as $taskChangeStatus) {
            if ($aRow['status'] != $taskChangeStatus['id']) {
                $outputStatus .= '<li>
                  <a href="#" onclick="task_mark_as(' . $taskChangeStatus['id'] . ',' . $aRow['id'] . '); return false;">
                     ' . _l('task_mark_as', $taskChangeStatus['name']) . '
                  </a>
               </li>';
            }
        }
        
        
        if ($status['id'])  {
        
            $calC = $calCminusrealcost = $realCost =0;
        }
        
        $outputStatus .= '</ul>';
        $outputStatus .= '</div>';
    }

    $outputStatus .= '</span>';

        $row[] = $outputStatus; 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWOwb.png
```

Comment: `if ($status['id'])` certainly won't work since it's not comparing to `52` in any way. Can you show how exactly you tried to _"replace id with 52"_?

Comment: Also, your title is about JS, but the code is only PHP. You might want to edit to reflect the actual nature of your issue.

Comment: i simply put if ($status['52']); but clearly didnt worked, and i also tried to do this: `$status = $id;
        
        if ($status['id'])  {
            $id = 52;
            $calC = $calCminusrealcost = $realCost =0;
        }` but still not worked

Comment: I figured. I suggest you revisit a tutorial about basics. In the meantime, you could read the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) about comparison operators.

Comment: `if ($status['id'] == 52)` I imagine. How to compare two values...this is the most basic of basics. Please go back to some beginner tutorials before you tie yourself in more knots over trivial stuff.

Comment: No problem. Now please go and make sure you understand _why_ it worked, so that you can use the same technique again in future :-) https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: I swear i will! :D